# Parceler: How to solve issue: error: Item is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, bundle, parcel, parceler

I tried to receive list items via Parceler `compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'` my code looks like:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<NavItem> navItems = new ArrayList<>();
        navItems.add(new CategoryItem("CategoryItem"));
        navItems.add(new SubCatItem("SubCatItem"));

        NavItemsWraper wraper = new NavItemsWraper(navItems);
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("data", Parcels.wrap(wraper));

        NavItemsWraper recievedWraper = Parcels.unwrap(data.getParcelableExtra("data"));
        recievedWraper.getNavItems();
        for (NavItem item:recievedWraper.getNavItems()){
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+item.title);
        }
    }
```

classes:

NavItem

```
@Parcel
public abstract class NavItem {
    public String title;

    public NavItem(){

    }

    public NavItem(String subCatItem) {
        this.title=subCatItem;
    }
}
```

NavItemsWrapper

```
@Parcel
public class NavItemsWraper {
    private  List<NavItem> navItems;

    public NavItemsWraper(){

    }

    public NavItemsWraper(List<NavItem> navItems) {

        this.navItems=navItems;
    }

    public List<NavItem> getNavItems() {
        return navItems;
    }
}
```

CategoryItem

```
@Parcel
public class CategoryItem extends NavItem {
    public CategoryItem(){

    }
    public CategoryItem(String categoryItem) {
        super(categoryItem);
    }
}
```

SubCategoryItem

```
@Parcel
public class SubCatItem extends NavItem {
    public SubCatItem() {
    }

    public SubCatItem(String subCatItem) {super(subCatItem);}
}
```

Compile error is:

```
...\app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\test\objs\NavItem$$Parcelable.java
Error:(63, 26) error: NavItem is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Parceler` can use abstract classes? Or sure that abstract classes can even be parceled? They need to be instantiated in order to be parceled, right?

Comment: @cricket_007 I posted the question to ask maybe anybody know about it

Comment: What happens if you remove the annotation from `NavItem`?

Comment: You don't need to tell me where I can or can't comment. I don't have an answer, so I don't post below. Anyways... The code is auto-generated. `app\build\generated\source\apt\debug\com\test\objs`, which means `Parceler` is trying to verify that it *can*, in fact, parcel your objects. Since you have an abstract class, it cannot pass that test

Comment: @cricket_007, I know that `Parceler` tried to create an instance of abstract class in auto-generated files, and question is "How to solve it?"

Comment: And I asked "What happens if you remove the annotation from `NavItem`?" One option if that doesn't work: don't make the class abstract. You are the developer, you should know that you don't need an instance of that class. Or make the constructor protected so you can't create it

Comment: And how about this issue? https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/237 or this one? https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/227

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks)). first is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding:

```
@Parcel(converter = NavigationItem.NavigationItemConverter.class)
public abstract class NavigationItem   {
```

...

```
 public static class NavigationItemConverter  implements ParcelConverter<NavigationItem> {

        public static final int KEY_CategoryItem = 1;
        public static final int KEY_SubCatItem = 2;
        @Override
        public void toParcel(NavigationItem input, android.os.Parcel parcel) {
            if (input == null) {
                parcel.writeInt(-1);
            } else {

                if (input instanceof CategoryItem) {
                    parcel.writeInt(KEY_CategoryItem);
                    parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap((CategoryItem) input), 0);
                }
                if (input instanceof SubCategoryItem) {
                    parcel.writeInt(KEY_SubCatItem);
                    parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap((SubCategoryItem) input), 0);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public NavigationItem fromParcel(android.os.Parcel parcel) {
            NavigationItem item = null;
            int key = parcel.readInt();
            if (key == KEY_CategoryItem){
                item = Parcels.unwrap(parcel.readParcelable(CategoryItem.class.getClassLoader()));
            }
            if (key == KEY_SubCatItem){
                item = Parcels.unwrap(parcel.readParcelable(SubCategoryItem.class.getClassLoader()));
            }
            return item;
        }
    }

    public static class NavigationListConverter  implements ParcelConverter<List<NavigationItem>> {

        @Override
        public void toParcel(List<NavigationItem> input, android.os.Parcel parcel) {
            if (input == null) {
                parcel.writeInt(-1);
            } else {
                parcel.writeInt(input.size());
                for (NavigationItem item : input) {
                    parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(item), 0);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<NavigationItem> fromParcel(android.os.Parcel parcel) {
            int size = parcel.readInt();
            if (size < 0) return null;
            List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                NavigationItem item = Parcels.unwrap(parcel.readParcelable(NavigationItem.class.getClassLoader()));
                items.add(item);
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
```

and added to

```
@Parcel
public class NavItemsWraper {
    @ParcelPropertyConverter(NavigationItem.NavigationListConverter.class)
    private  List<NavItem> navItems;
```